# Raspberry pi - How to run apache faster

Tags: apache, webserver, raspberry-pi

I am looking for method, how to run apache2 server faster on my raspberry.

Do You have any tips?

Or should I use another server app? ( I do not want to rebuild whole web again.

Thank you for Your suggestions, Krys

Comment: How many requests are you getting? Why do you think apache is slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say a lighter web server might suit the Pi better.  Have you tried lighthttpd or nginx?  How many req/sec are you getting and how many do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Well, I find one other solution. I found, that php-apc should solve my problem. I am going to try it. So wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Nginx. Small memory footprint and incredibly fast.  You can even use PHP with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep apache, and if you are using php, one thing you can do to speed up response time would be caching. This can dramatically reduce load time for dynamic web pages. In order to do that a solution I have used is PHP-APC. In order to use it, install it with `sudo apt-get install php-apc` and then configure it with  `cd /etc/php5/conf.d`, `sudo nano 20-apc.ini`, and then change the value after `apc.shm_size=` to 20M or more.

to the file (and do not forget to save the changes!).